# Check if Popup is open then close it

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile for my Applicaion .
In my page i have 5 popups as shown above

```
<div data-role="popup" id="one"    class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
    </div>

<div data-role="popup" id="two"    class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
    </div>

<div data-role="popup" id="three"    class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
    </div>
```

My requirement is that , 
On click of the device backup button , how can i check if any of the popup is open , close it

I have tried this code , but its not working

```
function homedeliverypagebackfunctionality() {

  if($("#one").hasClass("ui-popup-active"))
{
$( "#one" ).popup( "close" );
}

if($("#two").hasClass("ui-popup-active"))
{
$( "#two" ).popup( "close" );
}

if($("#three").hasClass("ui-popup-active"))
{
$( "#three" ).popup( "close" );
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to close any open popup:

```
$('[data-role="popup"]').popup("close");
```